# Google Sheets: lookup a value in a table then find right most non-blank value in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to create a google sheet formula that will lookup the ID and return the right-most non-blank score from columns 'Score A', 'Score B' and Score 'D'. Any help would be much appreciated!

| ID | Score A | Score B | Score C | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2342 | 65 | 43 |  | A |
| 8797 |  |  |  | B |
| 2343 | 23 | 45 | 98 | F |
| 6666 | 23 |  |  | B |
| 2333 | 67 | 43 |  | B |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming E1 is your search_key here's what you can try:

```
=LET(ζ,TOROW(XLOOKUP(E1,A2:A,B2:D),1),INDEX(ζ,,COUNTA(ζ)))
```

Comment: This was working but it seems Google has now suspended the TOROW formula !

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
=ifna(lookup(9^9,xlookup(F1,A:A,B:D)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you explain why you used the number 9^9 ? Unfortunately the formula is not working for me.

Comment: 9^9 is a random big number and it is unlikely for lookup to find this number in the search range or higher value than that. so the function resorts to returning the last found value in that range. Is it completely throwing an error when you try this formula OR showcasing non-last values?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately I have not been able to get your proposed solution to work. I'm getting the error: "Did not find value '387420489' in LOOKUP evaluation."

Comment: the formula works only for numerical scores. the error most likely states that you might be using it against text-based scores/grades or so!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the case! My scores are letters! Thank you. I should have made my question more clear.

Comment: Do you know if its better in this situation to edit the question or post a new one?

Comment: if its a fresh scenario; its advisable to post new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following formula. It concatenates for each row the 3 columns into one string and extracts via regex all characters after the last space.

```
=VLOOKUP(2342,
    {
     A:A,
     ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(B:B&" "&C:C&" "&D:D),"\b(\w+)$")))
    },
 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for adding one more option. It won't matter if they're numbers or not, neither if you have empty cells; it will find the non empty cell most to the right

```
=LET(r,INDEX(2:1000,XMATCH(E1,A2:A)), INDEX (r,,MAX(COLUMN(r)*(r<>""))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. I should have specified in my question that my data table has other data columns to the right of the Score A, B, C columns. So, the solution needs to be a formula that parse specific columns and not all columns to the right.

Comment: I've created a new question as should have also specified that the scores are letters and not numbers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75503676/google-sheets-lookup-a-value-in-a-table-then-find-right-most-non-blank-value-in