# Google Sheets: lookup a value in a table then find right most non-blank value in specified columns

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a google sheet formula that will lookup the ID and return the right-most non-blank score from columns 'Score A', 'Score B' and Score 'D'. Any help would be much appreciated!

| ID | Score A | Score B | Score C | Latency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2342 | C | C+ |  | 44 |
| 8797 |  |  |  | 67 |
| 2343 | A | B | D | 65 |
| 6666 | A+ |  |  | 22 |
| 2333 | D | D+ |  | 98 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for both text-grades and numerical scores

```
=lambda(Σ,ifna(index(Σ,match(2,1/(Σ<>"")))))(xlookup(G1,A:A,B:D,))
```

[image]